# Regex for use with PHP's preg_match() to find a newline

Tags: php, newline, expression

I'm fairly new/rusty with regular expressions.  I'm collecting a block of text from a textarea element and I want to check to see if the person who filled it used any paragraphs, amongst other things.

I'm using the following and I know it's wrong.

```
preg_match('/\r\n|\n|\r/', $_GET['text']);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regex is not wrong. But for detecting paragraphs you will want to look for two consecutive newlines:

```
 preg_match('/(\r?\n){2}/'
```

The carriage return `\r` is optional, and I would just check for `\n` newline as most platforms treat that as linebreak. Obviously this check will fail if the submitted text is just a single line without paragraphs or newlines.

Alternatively you could also probe for two newlines with *any sort* of whitespace in between:

```
 preg_match('/(\s*\n){2}/'
```

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions, unfortunately, neither of those have worked for me.  So, a little more detail: I've written a script that reads a block of text and analyses it for basic features of writing.  A csv file defines a series of rules, each one having an associated regular expression.
Here's the CSV record with one of the expressions you suggested.

Paragraph(s),W,3,a,p,"/(\s*\n){2}/",Start a new paragraph with every new focus.,

It's loaded by fgetcsv and then tested with preg_match.  Could this process be affecting it? Many thanks for your time, any further help really appreciated.

Comment: While in CSV it is an escape sequence, `fgetcsv` should leave `\n` alone. But you should rather print the regex out for debugging purposes. (The regex works well in my tests.)

Comment: It prints out as /(\s*\n){2}/, exactly as it is in the csv.  I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: Print out the `$_GET["text"]` and compare via view source if it really contains newlines.

Comment: Ah ha! Interesting.  It doesn't have new lines.  Even though it does in the textarea.  Does the GET method strip out that stuff?

Comment: Or does this?    xmlHttp.open("GET", "/te_english/te_z_shortreport.php?text="+document.getElementById('element_1').value, true);

Comment: I'm thinking that it must do.  I'll have to investigate using POST instead, or try storing it in my sql db temporarily.

Comment: If you add it as GET parameter, you need to apply `encodeURIComponent()` or `escape()` on the textbox `.value` Else you are at the mercy of how the browser appends it.

Comment: You're a star.  Thanks so much for your help, it's working! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

> This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.
>
> And this is another. And this is another. And this is another. And this is another. And this is another. And this is another. And this is another. And this is another. And this is another. And this is another.

You could just do:

```
if (str_replace("\r\n\r\n", '', $str) != $str)
  // the input contains at least two paragraphs
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'm trying to keep it with preg_match as it's processing a series of rules from a csv file in a loop, but I'll keep your solution in mind and give it a go.

Comment: I gave that a go but it always returns positive, even if there are no paragraphs in the textarea:    if (str_replace("\r\n\r\n", '', $text) == $text) echo 'Paragraphs detected.';   Thanks for your help, any further ideas?

Comment: @Ed Fearon Indeed. I modified the condition.